# How to find the peakpoint in z direction after fitting a 3D surface in matlab

Tags: matlab, surface

I have fitted the 3D surface and just want to know how to find the max value of z direction after fitting, not the max value that I gave, it would be just noise. The code can be seen as followed.

```
    x=[0 6.8 18.6 21.3 3 12.5 13 20.7 17.7 20.8 1.1 6.3 13.2 3.4 3.5 18.9 11.3 13.1];
y=[1.7 1.1 0.8 1.2 3.1 3 3.1 4.2 4.1 5.8 6.4 5.8 7.4 5.3 5.9 9.7 7.6 10.7];
z=[0.59 0.58 0.53 1.25 1.26 0.2 0.18 0.14 0.64 0. 1.06 0.73 0.15 0.15 0.1 0.08 0.17 0.8];
scatter3(x,y,z)
x=x';
y=y';
z=z';
hold on
Z=[ones(length(x),1),x,y,x.^2,x.*y,y.^2,x.^3,x.^2.*y,x.*y.^2,y.^3];
A=Z\z;
X=min(x)-1:0.2:max(x)+1;
Y=min(y)-1:(max(y)-min(y)+2)/(length(X)+1):max(y)+1;
[x y]=meshgrid(X,Y);
z=A(1)+A(2)*x+A(3)*y+A(4)*x.^2+A(5)*x.*y+A(6)*y.^2+A(7)*x.^3+A(8)*x.^2.*y+A(9)*x.*y.^2+A(10)*y.^3;
mesh(x,y,z)
```

Comment: You seem to replace `z` in the end, destroying the previous values. Therefore if you just find the max value of `z` after you computed it, should be enough.

Comment: do you simply need `zmax = max(z(:)) ` ? Or `[row col] = find(z == max(z(:)))` if you want the position.

Comment: OK, I got it. Another qustion is: When I make x,y,z into a x matrix and use the syntax surf(x), how should I change the following code to get the surface fitting?